# Will the RPi-4 work with a Logitech K830 keyboard?

Tags: bluetooth, keyboard

Ideally in Bluetooth mode? But at least in wireless mode with a dongle.
Pi runs Raspbian & connects to family TV & is wirelessly connected to home network.
Therefore, is ideal to have a back-lit 'living-room' keyboard with integral mouse pad & not consuming any USB slots. 
I know this is nominally a Windows keyboard but suspect that will not be an issue(?). 
And if this is doable, are then any special instructions or tricks one should know about to make it work?

Comment: I think it should work fine, but I don't have one to test so I can't guarantee it. I can confirm I haven't had any problems with my Logitech K400 keyboard and it's Logitech unified receiver under Linux.

Comment: Thanks for that, Fred. The K400 doesn't have Bluetooth or back-lighting I think - but it's good to know the OS being Linux doesn't matter.

Comment: @user109319, K830 uses Bluetooth and 2.4G Wireless Unifying.  I have been using a couple of Logitechs for Rpi4B buster and there is no need to do any configuration. However, I do find problems linking Bluetooth AV devices to Rpi3/4, using BlueZ5.5.

Comment: Thank you - then I think I'll get a K830 & be content with using the unifying receiver :-)

Comment: @user109319, Welcome and good luck.  Cheers.

Answer (score 2):

So, I know I’m late to the party but since I was searching for the same problem and this is one of the top results I decided to post my solution.

Select the Bluetooth icon.
Add Device.

Select the `K830`.
Press Pair.

It should say that it paired successfully but not work.

Select the Bluetooth icon again.

Turn Off Bluetooth.

Select Turn on Bluetooth.

Add Device.

Select the `K830` again.

Press Pair.

The keyboard should now work.

Weirdly while trying to verify these instructions to make sure that the instructions were correct or it was that the keyboard Bluetooth discovery timed out I discovered something else...

Press the Bluetooth icon.

Remove device.

Select the `K830` and press Remove.

Press the Bluetooth icon.

Add device.

Select the `K830` and Pair.

Now it asks you to type in the pairing code on the keyboard.
I seriously doubt many people will see this, but there it is.

Cheers,
Chris